# Reactjs:Infinite Scroll not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, redux, axios

I'm trying to add infinite scroll in my web application.When the user scrolls down the page, there must be an API call to load the data beneath the existing data.So, the problem here is when I reach the bottom of the web page, the API is not being called.

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

 class InfiniteData extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state={olddata: [],newData: [], requestSent: false}
}
componentDidMount(){
  window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleOnScroll);
  this.doQuery();
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleOnScroll);
}

doQuery() {
  console.log("indoquery");
  axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
  .then( res=>
  this.setState({
    olddata: res.data,
    newData: this.state.olddata.concat(this.state.olddata)
  })
  )
  .catch(console.log("error"))
}
handleOnScroll(){
  var scrollTop = (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) || document.body.scrollTop;
  var scrollHeight = (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollHeight) || document.body.scrollHeight;
  var clientHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight || window.innerHeight;
  var scrolledToBottom = Math.ceil(scrollTop + clientHeight) >= scrollHeight;

  if (scrolledToBottom) {
     console.log("At bottom");
    // enumerate a slow query
     setTimeout(this.doQuery, 2000);
  }
}
  render()
  {
    return (
    <div>
      <div className="data-container">
        {this.state.newData && this.state.newData.map((dat,i)=>
          <div key={i}>
            {dat.body}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default InfiniteData;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually just an obscured case of not binding `this` correctly: the following line calls `handleOnScroll` using `window` (**not** the InfiniteData component instance) as `this`:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleOnScroll);
```

Then, your `setTimeout` call is trying to call `this.doQuery`, which is `undefined` since `window.doQuery` doesn't exist.

If you bind `this` correctly for the EventListener, this should work out: either change to `window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleOnScroll.bind(this));` in `componentDidMount` or add the following line inside the `constructor` to keep it bound across the board:

```
this.handleOnScroll = this.handleOnScroll.bind(this)
```

---

Note: this isn't the problem you're having, but be careful inside your `setState` call--do you mean to use `newData: this.state.olddata.concat(res.data)`? (passing `res.data` to the `concat` call)

Comment: thank you so much @daniel for your well descriptive answer.As you mentioned, using concat in the setState is a bad approach or it leads to further problem,what is the right way to merge the new data with the prev state data ?Please help me with this.

Comment: @karthik concat is probably fine, it's just that you were calling `this.state.olddata.concat(this.state.olddata)` which is just doubling the old data instead of adding the new stuff! My guess is you just need one `data` element in state (`this.state.data`) and have that `setState` call be `this.setState({ data: this.state.data.concat(res.data) })`. If you need to keep track of old data you can still do that, but from what you have posted here you don't need it

Comment: Yeah,i have changed it to `newData: this.state.newData.slice().concat(res)`.it works fine now

Answer (score 0):

Following should work.

```
import React from "react";

function doQuery() {
  console.log("indoquery");
  // Do something here
}
class InfiniteData extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={olddata: [],newData: [], requestSent: false}
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleOnScroll);
        doQuery();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleOnScroll);
    }


    handleOnScroll(){
        // ..... 
       if (scrolledToBottom) {
           setTimeout(function () {doQuery()}, 2000);
       }
    }
    render() {
        return (
           <div>

           </div>
        );
    }
}

export default InfiniteData;
```

Note that I have removed some code to make it compact and easier for you to understand where the problem lies. Basically the fix is where you define the doQuery function and how you pass that function to setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel Thompson stated, the problem is that you do not bind this. To elaborate: when the eventListener invokes the function `this` will not be bound to your component, but rather to `window`.

Binding `this` in the event listener will solve the problem of the code not being called, but will create a new problem. When you call `handleOnScroll.bind(this)` a new function is created, so when you try to un-register it, it will not unregister. To get both registration and unregistration to work as expected, save that new function and use it to register/unregister.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    // Need to bind 'this' to refer to component.
    // This will create a new function which will have to be stored so it can be unregistered
    this.scrollListener = this.handleOnScroll.bind(this);
    this.state={olddata: [],newData: [], requestSent: false}
}

componentDidMount(){
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollListener);
    this.doQuery();
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.scrollListener);
}
```